# Free Body Diagram w.r.t a rotating reference frame

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, free-body-diagram

According to my physics textbook,

> $1)$ When analysing the statics of a particle of mass $m$ from a reference frame which is rotating with angular speed $\omega$, we need to add a pseudo force known as centrifugal force, apart from other real forces acting on the particle.

> $2)$ If the particle has a velocity when observed from a rotating frame, in general, there will be two pseudo forces acting on it———— Centrifugal force and Coriolis force

While I understand these two points, what I want to know is, if we draw a free-body-diagram of an object from a rotating frame, and the object has a velocity relative to the rotating frame, don’t we include the real forces acting on the object along with the two fictitious forces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, of course we include the real forces. Real forces would be included in both inertial as well as non-inertial frames. But in non-inertial frames we have to additionally include pseudo forces, such as those you mention.

Comment: Thank you. While I knew it would be very strange if we did not include the real forces, I wanted to be 100% sure